# How to fix delete button not working in Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a delete button in Laravel, but it redirects me to a white page.
this is the html code for the delete button (it's an icon):

```
<a class="icon" href="{{ route('capteurs.destroy', $capteur->id)}}" data-balloon="Supprimer" data-balloon-pos="right">
    <i class="fe fe-trash-2" ></i>
</a>
```

`destroy` function in the controller class:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
  $capteur = Capteur::find($id);
  $capteur->delete();
  return redirect('/capteurs')->with('success', 'Capteur Supprimé');
}
```

I'm supposed to be redirected to `/capteurs` which is this page:
[image]

Instead i get redirected here, and the element i wanna delete is still there:

[image]

Edit: Routes for capteurs

```
Route::resource('capteurs', 'CapteurController');
```

Comment: Could you post the routes file? (capteurs and capteurs.destroy should be enough)

Comment: @Stormhammer Edited!

Comment: I edited my answer a bit. Could you try it?

Comment: when you using route resource, delete endpoint would be `DELETE /capteurs/{id}` but you send a `GET` request to `/capteurs/{id}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should make a form for that:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('capteurs.destroy', $capteur->id)}}"
  @csrf
  @method('DELETE')
  <a class="icon" data-balloon="Supprimer" data-balloon-pos="right">
  </a>
  <button type="submit"><i class="fe fe-trash-2" ></i></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `form` around your anchor tag and next thing you need is a `DELETE` request instead of `GET`. You can try the below code:

```
<form action="{{ route('capteurs.destroy', $capteur->id) }}" method="POST">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type='submit' class="btn btn-danger" ><i class="fe fe-trash-2" ></i></button>
</form>
```

If you really want it to do with the anchor tag then give a specific `id` to your anchor tag and do an ajax request!

Answer (score 0):

You're currently linking to your destroy page like its a GET request, while it should be a POST request. If execute `php artisan route:list` it will show information on the routes.

To fix this:

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('capteurs.destroy', $capteur->id) }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button><i class="fe fe-trash-2" ></i></button>
</form>
```

You'll probably have to edit styling a bit though